# Interfacing to a 3rd-party library enum design issue

Tags: c, enums

I have a sound library that defines the following enum:

`libsnd.h`:

```
enum sample_format {
    signed_16bit_little_endian,
    signed_16bit_big_endian,
    //etc
};
```

I'm designing an application that is supposed to have sample format configurable. Percisely

`application.h`:

```
#include <libsnd.h>                 //<--- libsnd Here

typedef struct app_config_t app_config_t
app_config_t *cfgalloc();
void set_sample_format(app_config_t *cfg_ptr, enum sample_format sf);
```

`main.c`

```
#include <libsnd.h>                 //<--- libsnd Here
#include "application.h"

int main(int agrc, char *argv[]){
    enum sample_format sf = //parse arguments and extract sample format
    app_config_t *cfg_ptr = cfgalloc();
    set_sample_format(cfg_ptr, sf); //<--- libsnd Here
}
```

With such an approach I currently see the following problems:

1. It introduces a tight coupling to the `libsnd.h` so switching to another library is painfull.
2. In case the `libsnd` is not implemented to some specific platform I want to port my application to it will require either implementing it myself or tons of `#ifdef`-like macro across the whole application.

The solution to the problem I see is to define my own enum in the

`application.h`:

```
enum app_sample_format {
    signed_16bit_little_endian,
    signed_16bit_big_endian,
    //etc
};
```

which would left the portability issues to `application.c` file. But this is sort of boilerplate I would like to avoid. What is the common way to approach such a problem?

Comment: If you plan on/foresee using multiple libraries, create an interface that they must supply. Then write a single file tightly coupled to the library that provides that interface. You will have to write a new interface implementation for each library you use, but if the interfaces is designed correctly, nothing else in the program will need to change.

Comment: @madscientist, that would have been a fine answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist In my particular case I need to be able to configure `sample_rate`. So I create an interface in my `application.h` providing the application specific sample rates. Then in the implementation file I map this rates to a library's rates. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: As I understand the comment, @MadPhysicist is saying that if you know you will use multiple sound libraries in the future, then write an interface for each library to make each library work with your application. That means you will have to write the interface for each different library you use, but you are free to set your application interface in some fixed manner and make the libraries work with it. On to your original question, using your own `enum` is reasonable way to go. Then with each different library you map the library values to your `enum` in each case.